# How to make link button in Lazarus?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I want to make a hyperlink into button. If the button has clicked, the default browser will open the link. I tried it with the Delphi version, but it doesn't work in Lazarus. Here is the code I tried. How do I make it in Lazarus version?

```
Uses ShellApi

begin
ShellExecute (0, 'Open', 'link website', '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Comment: This code will work on Windows, and since `ShellExecute` only exists on Windows, I presume that you are targeting Windows. Do you receive any errors? You are checking for errors when you call `ShellExecute`. Did you read its documentation? I doubt it, because that documentation tells you to call `ShellExecuteEx` instead. It does so because `ShellExecuteEx` is capable of reporting errors properly. My guess is that you have copied this code without gaining any real understanding of what it does. That approach is futile. Seek to understand.

Comment: [OpenURL](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lclintf/openurl.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShellExecute is something I never really use as I always try to make my programs cross platform. I always use TProcess or RunCommand instead. There's full documentation at the link below, which is pretty good.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs

If you really want to use ShellExecute then I note that in the link it does state the following about initialising COM:

ShellExecute is a standard MS Windows function (ShellApi.h) with good documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) (note their remarks about initialising COM if you find the function unreliable).

I hope this helps. If not I will try and help you further.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest cross-platform compatible way to open a link is provided by the [OpenURL](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lclintf/openurl.html) function. It is available in the *LCLIntf* unit, which comes bundled with Lazarus.

Example:

```
procedure OnClick;
var
  found: boolean;
begin
  found := OpenURL('http://nowhere.loopback.edu');
end;
```